# Scraping web with XML package in R

Tags: xml, r, web, screen-scraping

I need to scraping the table on the next website:

http://www.ign.gob.pe/index.php?PG=Nomenclatorp&OPC=21&paginasok=1

When I use this code:

```
library(XML)

url <- "http://www.ign.gob.pe/index.php?PG=Nomenclatorp&OPC=21&paginasok=1"
html <- htmlTreeParse(url,useInternalNodes=T)
readHTMLTable(html)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xmlNamespaceDefinitions") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlNamespaceDefinitions' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to try `readHTMLTable(readLines(url))` - it seems as if parsing chokes on \0 strings.

Comment: You should make that an answer @lukeA.

Comment: Thanks @lukeA, I think your solution can I be useful.

Comment: The url is not working anymore